# "Could not load NIB" when subclassing FUIAuthPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

The only related issue I could find online was an issue report on GitHub:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/128

However, there didn't seem to be any resolution.

Using FirebaseUI, I'd like to subclass `FUIAuthPickerViewController` so I can customize it a little. When I subclass and call `FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI!.authViewController`, I get the following runtime exception:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle

I'm new to Swift, so it's very possible I'm incorrectly subclassing `FUIAuthPickerViewController`, but everything I've read online points toward that not being the case.

Here's my subclass:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuthUI

class AuthViewController: FUIAuthPickerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

Here's my delegate:

```
public class AuthManager: NSObject, FUIAuthDelegate {
    // TODO: Implement TOS URL
    // TODO: Implement custom strings for multiple languages

    static let instance = AuthManager()
    private override init() {
        super.init()

        self.firebaseUI().delegate = self;
        self.firebaseUI().providers = [FUIGoogleAuth(), FUIFacebookAuth()]
    }

    public func firebaseUI() -> FUIAuth {
        return FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!
    }

    public func firebase() -> FIRAuth {
        return FIRAuth.auth()!
    }

    public func addStateChangeListener(listener: @escaping FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerBlock) {
        self.firebase().addStateDidChangeListener(listener)
    }

    public func showLoginFrom(viewController: UIViewController) {
        viewController.present(self.firebaseUI().authViewController(),
                               animated: true,
                               completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: FUIAuthDelegate

    public func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: FIRUser?, error: Error?) {

    }

    public func authPickerViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController {
        return AuthViewController(authUI: authUI)
    }
}
```

If I remove the default `FUIAuthPickerViewController` everything works fine.  I just assumed by subclass would inherit its NIB from its parent if one wasn't defined.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Cohen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in FirebaseUI that has resurfaced from an older version.

The issue can be tracked [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/128).

A temporary solution is to hardcode the correct NIB name in your `FUIAuthPickerController` subclass:

Swift:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuthUI

class AuthViewController: FUIAuthPickerViewController {

    override init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?, authUI: FUIAuth) {
        super.init(nibName: "FUIAuthPickerViewController", bundle: bundle, authUI: authUI)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

Objective-C:

```
@implementation CustomAuthPickerViewController
...

 - (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
                         bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
                         authUI:(FUIAuth *)authUI {

     self = [super initWithNibName:@"FUIAuthPickerViewController"
                           bundle:nibBundleOrNil
                           authUI:authUI];

    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Your Title";
     }

    return self;
} 

...
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

`FUIAuthPickerViewController` is a `UIViewController`.

[The `init` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-init) for that class says:

> If you specify nil for the nibName parameter and you do not override the loadView() method, the view controller searches for a nib file as described in the nibName property.

[The `nibName` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname) says:

> Specifically, it looks for a nib file with an appropriate name
>   (without the .nib extension) and loads that nib file whenever its view
>   is requested. Specifically, it looks (in order) for a nib file with
>   one of the following names:
>
> 1. If the view controller class name ends with the word ‘Controller’, as in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the
>      class name without the word ‘Controller’, as in MyView.nib.
> 2. It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController,
>      it looks for a MyViewController.nib file.

There's nothing here to suggest it would check the names of all superclasses for nibs.  I assume it's checking "AuthView.nib" and "AuthViewController.nib", and then giving up.

Comment: That makes sense, and if that's the case, the FirebaseUI documentation is extremely vague on the process, saying all you need to do is subclass and implement a delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

This also seems to be caused by a bug on FirebaseUI, I had the same problem and implemented several solutions but it only worked after I did pod update from Firebase 4.1.0 to Firebase 4.1.1.

This git [repo](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/128) also claims that the bug was fixed in this update.

You can see what version you are currently at by doing:
'pod search FirebaseUI' in terminal in your project's path location, if it is not the latest version, just do 'pod update' and this hopefully solves the problem.